# Pegando um elemento pelo id depois do repeat em um array - HTML/JavaScript/Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Olá,
Estou precisando pegar um elemento no HTML depois de um ng-repeat, para aplicar comandos de CSS na div no qual depende do resultado que vier do banco de dados. Por enquanto eu apenas consigo pegar esse elemento, porém é aplicado o Style apenas no primeiro item do repeat, e eu preciso aplicar nos demais também com diferentes Style's. Tem alguma maneira melhor de pegar esse elemento através de um index?

Código HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "fornecedor in fornecedores" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
        <td>{{fornecedor.nome}}</td>
        <td>
           <div class="chart-agendamento">
                <div id="agendamento">{{fornecedor.agendamento}}</div>
            </div>
        </td>
<tr>
```

Código JavaScript

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.fornecedores.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('agendamento').style.width="100px";
    }
```

O que eu preciso fazer é basicamente pegar esse id do "Agendamento" junto com algum index que retorna da tabela no HTML, de forma que eu consiga fazer o for rodar. Alguém sabe alguma forma de usar esse getElementById funcionando dessa maneira? Ou alguma maneira melhor de fazer o que eu quero de formas diferente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode ter dois elementos com o mesmo id (identificador) no seu HTML. O CSS só está sendo aplicado somente ao primeiro por causa disso.

O que você pode fazer é adicionar uma class:

```
<div class="agendamento">{{fornecedor.agendamento}}</div>
```

Dessa forma você pode aplicar um CSS a todos os elementos da class agendamento assim:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {        

        document.getElementsByClassName('agendamento').style.width="100px";
}
```

Se você precisa colocar um estilo diferente para cada elemento, você vai precisar diferenciá-los de alguma forma no ng-repeat dando um id diferente para cada um deles e depois fazendo o mesmo processo no for.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Através da sua resposta fui estudar o getElementsByClassName e descobri que ele me retorna um array de elementos, e dessa forma consigo identificar qual elemento quero referenciar através da sequência. Valeu :)